# Get the months name for the a particular date range

Tags: java, mysql

I have a date range '2015/01/01' to '2015/12/31'. 
My database has date,device_id columns of table "device".

From this date range i want to display the 
month-name and № of unique `device_id`s in that month.
E.g, my database having `date` and `devie_id` are two columns

```
date        device_id

2015-01-01     1
2015-01-20     1
2015-03-01     1
2015-03-01     3
2015-04-01     2
2015-06-01     3
2015-08-01     4
2015-09-01     1
```

expected result

```
Month   device_count
January      1
March        2
April        1
June         1
August       1
September    1
```

How to bring the month `Name`?
I am using java class to retrive the data.

Below is the image for clear idea of the result which i needed

[image]

Comment: [MySQL DATE_FORMAT() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select month(date),count(distinct device_id) from table_name group by month(date);
```

Comment: thanks even i too used the same way to solve the issue

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(`date`,"%M") AS 'Month',
COUNT(DISTINCT device_id) AS device_count
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`,"%Y-%m");
```

Please check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd68f7/1/0)

**Result:**

You will get output like below:

```
Month   device_count
January      1
March        2
April        1
June         1
August       1
September    1
```

**Note:**

`%M Month name (January-December)`

`%Y Year, numeric, four digits`

`%m Month, numeric (00-12)`

You can check [**`MYSQL DATE_FORMAT`**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

**Caution:**

The reason behind grouping by **year,month** pair is to make sure that the same months across different years don't get summed up in the same slot.
The following example might give you an hint:

`SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('2016-04-14','%Y-%m-%d'));`

**Result:** `4`

`SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('2014-04-14','%Y-%m-%d'));`

**Result:** `4`

Comment: Thanks a lot . DATE_FORMAT(`date`,"%M")  helped me alot

Comment: You are welcome. Please keep in mind the **CAUTION** section in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT device_id, 
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%b') AS AddDate
    FROM device
```

this might work for you but you should reffer this [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)  to see how `DATE_FORMAT` works.

Comment: Thanks DATE_FORMAT have may formats just using this method which is very easy way of approach